# Are CSS Variables a part of the official W3C Specification?

Tags: css, w3c

Most major browsers support css-variables at this point but my question is whether or not it is officially a part of the W3C Specification.

The latest document I have been able to find is from 2015 here: https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/CR-css-variables-1-20151203/

The document says it would remain a Candidate Recommendation at least until 1 June 2016 but I have not been able to find anything past this point about its status.

Comment: For answers to such a question I check [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables). It seems all modern browser support it, but there is no official spec

Comment: @MichaëlHompus Support is not the same thing as a spec., which is what the question is about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[This page](https://www.w3.org/standards/techs/css#)** clearly shows it's still in the Candidate Recommendation phase. Also, clicking the **["Latest Version"](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/)** of the spec. link will always show you the most up-to-date status. It really doesn't matter if somewhere inside the document it mentions another date. But, what you read simply means that it will be a CR until, **at a minimum**, 6/1/16. The W3C works slowly and it could still be years until it becomes an official standard.